# getting Enum value assigned to JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, enums

I Have a `class` that contains an `Enum` and a `class` with a `JButton`. I am able to set an `Enum` value to my button, but I can not get my value back – it simply prints out `null` How should I retrive the value ??

```
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Test extends JFrame {

public Test() {

    MyButton button = new MyButton();
    button.setState(State.CROSS);

    button.getState();
    System.out.println(button.getState());
}

public enum State {

    CROSS

    {

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "X";
        }
    },
}

class MyButton extends JButton {
    State state;

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test v = new Test();
}

}
```

Comment: You `setState` method is empty, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setState() does nothing, change it to:

```
public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
```